# Mongoose save method not working

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am creating a social media app with messaging functionality, My problem is in storing saved messages where I am looking up the id of the sender then using .save() to store the message.

The updated version of the doc logs fine from the callback but it doesn't save in the db for some reason :/

Any help will be appreciated

```
var MessageSchema = new Schema({
    client_id: Number,
    messages: [{ client_id: Number, messages: [] }]
```

//nested messages should look like [{type: "sent", message:"some message" }, .....]
    });

```
    socket.on("send_message", (data, friend_id, me_id) => {
        Message.findOne({ client_id: me_id }, (err, doc) => {
            doc.messages.map(
                i =>
                    i.client_id == friend_id
                        ? i.messages.push({ type: "sent", message: data })
                        : null
            );
            doc.save(function(err, updated) {
                if (err) {
                    console.error("ERROR!");
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to first explicitly define the nested messages array schema:

```
var MessageSchema = new Schema({
    client_id: Number,
    messages: [{ 
        client_id: Number, 
        messages: [{
            type: { type: String },
            data: String
        }] 
    }]
})
```

Saving data would require using the **[`findOneAndUpdate()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#findoneandupdate_findOneAndUpdate)** method as follows:

```
Message.findOneAndUpdate(
    { 'client_id': me_id, 'messages.client_id': friend_id }, 
    { '$push': {'messages.$.messages': { 'type': 'sent', 'message': data } },
    { 'new': true } 
    (err, message) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error("ERROR!");
        } else {
            console.log(message);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Awesome and thanks! I had no idea about that $ inside the update condition.

Comment: No worries. The `$` is the [positional operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) which identifies an element in an array to update without explicitly specifying the position of the element in the array.